# .htaccess remove index.htm for requests on Drupal 6 site

Tags: drupal, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal-6

- Converting large static site to
  Drupal 6.2
- Page urls are now aliased like "folder/"
  "folder/subfolder/"
- Problem is hundreds of
  inbound links that point to
  "sub.example.com/folder/index.htm"

I'd rather not have to include that filename in my aliases and was hoping I could just htaccess rewrite those requests to the base directories since they're all the same format but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

Been trying to use this, placed before Drupal's rewrite rules in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

or this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.(html|php)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.(html|php)?$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel dumb, thought I had tried it with the L and R swapped but I guess not, this worked perfect for both bits I tried.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*/index\.(php|html)\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)index\.(php|html)$ /$1 [L=301,R]
```